# Codeigniter User Sessions Validation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, cookies

So I was thinking about using CodeIgniter to build an application as to where my clients can register etc. However, I've been looking at the documentation about the sessions, and I was a little confused as to how the cookie data/session data is validated. Could somebody please clear this up for me? I will give my interpretation of how I think it works.

The user logs in -> Session is created and stored session id and email in cookie -> On each page load the cookie data is checked in the database to confirm users session id matches their user agent, ip and perhaps other things?

I'm sorry as to if that is horribly wrong, but I'm having a hard time understanding the logic with securing a session. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is straight from Codeigniter manual:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

How do Sessions work?

When a page is loaded, the session class will check to see if valid session data exists in the user's session cookie. If sessions data does not exist (or if it has expired) a new session will be created and saved in the cookie. If a session does exist, its information will be updated and the cookie will be updated. With each update, the session_id will be regenerated.

It's important for you to understand that once initialized, the Session class runs automatically. There is nothing you need to do to cause the above behavior to happen. You can, as you'll see below, work with session data or even add your own data to a user's session, but the process of reading, writing, and updating a session is automatic.

Comment: Yes, and this is straight from my post. 'I've been looking at the documentation about the sessions, and I was a little confused as to how the cookie data/session data is validated.' If I didn't get it by reading the documentation, I don't think I'll get it be reading a quoted version of it in your answer. I asked for a decent understanding.

Comment: The above is very understandable, but to explain further a session ID which is a random string is used to cross reference with the data in the session table. The string is then regenerated / encrypted with every request and updated in the cookie and the table. If the session table doest match the cookie the data cannot be accessed.

Comment: I would also recommend you store your sessions in a Database. They work better when storing more data such as Cart data etc and would also be more secure.